# rvest: select and scrape html table(s) after a specific (title) string

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape the following website with public healthcare data: 
https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/Grupa.aspx?id=Qpc6nYOpOBQ%3d

I would like to scrape only a table or tables that are preceded with a title 
"Tabela xx procedury ICD-9" where xx is not a fixed number.

There may be 1 but occasionally 2-3 such tables on the page. And they can occur in different order with other pages, so it is not possible to indicate I want n'th page on the website.

For instance, I am interested only in tables in the same page that are preceded by "Icd-9 main" string and skip others. There are 2 such tables and I would like to scrape their content to a data.frame. They may not appear in the same order as below, so **I must rely on preceding string**. Occasionally there will be no Icd-9 main table at all.

```
Page
----
Icd-10
====
Table
====

Icd-9 main
====
Table
===

Icd-9 main
====
Table
====


Icd-9 supplementary
====
Table
===
```

I am only aware of the code that selects the nth table in order like in this tutorial:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/

```
library("rvest")
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population"
population <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()
population <- population[[1]]
```

whereby all the tables are dumped into a list and then we can select which table we want by number

However in my case I never know which table to scrape, the order may vary, it can be 2 tables preceded by a string containing "Tabela xx: procedury ICD-9"

**My question is, how to select and scrape html tables based on preciding title or description string. Or a table or tables appearing only immediately after a string containing e.g "Tabela xx procedury ICD-9"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

doc <- read_html("https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/Grupa.aspx?id=Qpc6nYOpOBQ%3d")

# extract all the nodes that have the title (id = "tytul") or a table
# the cs selector "," is like a boolean OR. 
nodes <- doc %>% html_nodes(".tytul,table")

# loop though each node.
signal <- FALSE
my_tables <- list()
j <- 0
for (i in 1:length(nodes)) {

  # if title signal previously set and this is a table tag
  if (signal & html_name(nodes[i]) == "table") {
    cat("Match..\n")

    # get the table (data frame)
    this_table <- html_table(nodes[i], fill = TRUE, header = TRUE)[[1]]

    # append to list
    j = j + 1
    my_tables[[j]] <- this_table

    # and reset the signal so we search for the next one
    signal <- FALSE
  }

  # if the signal is clear look for matching title
  if (!signal) {
    signal <- nodes[i] %>% html_text() %>% str_detect("Tabela.+ICD 9")
  }
}
my_tables[[1]][1:5,]
my_tables[[2]][1:5,]

# > my_tables[[1]][1:5,]
# ICD 9                                                    Nazwa Lb. hospitalizacji UdziaĹ\u0082 (%) Mediana czasu pobytu (dni)
# 1 2.051       ZaĹ\u0082oĹźenie pĹ\u0082ytki sztucznej do czaszki                168            32,31                          7
# 2 1.247 Kraniotomia z usuniÄ\u0099ciem krwiaka podtwardĂłwkowego                 55            10,58                         20
# 3 2.022                       Odbarczenie zĹ\u0082amania czaszki                 43             8,27                          6
# 4 2.040                 Przeszczep kostny do koĹ\u009bci czaszki                 35             6,73                          8
# 5 1.093                        Inne aspiracje w zakresie czaszki                 33             6,35                          5
# > my_tables[[2]][1:5,]
# ICD 9                                         Nazwa Lb. hospitalizacji UdziaĹ\u0082 (%) Mediana czasu pobytu (dni)
# 1    O35                                     SĂłd (Na)                239            45,96                          8
# 2  89.00          Porada lekarska, konsultacja, asysta                230            44,23                          9
# 3    N45                                     Potas (K)                217            41,73                          8
# 4 87.030                  TK gĹ\u0082owy bez kontrastu                214            41,15                          9
# 5  89.04 Opieka pielÄ\u0099gniarki lub poĹ\u0082oĹźnej                202            38,85                          8
```

Comment: This is great epi99. Fabulous!. God bless you, you helped me a lot, get me started. How did you learn it! Can you recommend a good source?

Comment: @JacekKotowski, this is mostly basic procedural programming (loops and switches and not a good style for R)  which would be taught by text or class for intro to programming say with Java.  For the web scraping, understanding the structure of html (the DOM) and learning about CSS.selectors will help. ) Use the "inspect elements" in your browser  to understand web page structure. On the R side I have paid  a lot of attention to Hadley Wickham's packages "hadleyverse"